# how to retrieve dynamically added checkbox selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am adding checkbox dynamically to my html page. how can i retrieve the values when user makes selection.

```
var sources = source_names_list;
$.each(sources, function(index,value) {
    // var checkbox1 = "<label for="+test+"<input type='checkbox' id=\"+test+\" value=\"+test+\" name=\"+test+\"></label>"
    // var checkbox="<label for="+value+">"+value+"<input type='checkbox' id="+value+" value="+value+" name="+value+"></label></br>"
    var checkbox1 = "<p><label><input type=\"checkbox\" id="+value+" class=\"filled-in\"/><span>" + value + "</span></label></p>"
    $("#sources").append($(checkbox1));
});
```

I tried accessing them using their id and it didn't work.

Comment: What does this have to do with python?

Comment: Can you post the `source_name_list`?

Comment: source_name_list = [ 'news' ,'info','article'];

Comment: var source_name_list = ['apple','oranges','banana'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the values using the class name `filled-in` as a selector. You will also need to add a `value` to each generated checkbox.

```js
// Sources
var source_name_list = ['news' , 'info', 'article', 'newyork,items'];

// Create all the checkboxes (adding a value to each one)
$.each(source_name_list, function(index,value) {
    var checkbox = '<p><label><input type="checkbox" id="'+value+'" value="' + value + '" class="filled-in" /><span>' + value + '</span></label></p>';
    $("#sources").append($(checkbox));
});

// "get selected" button
$('#get').click(function() {

  // Create an array for the values
  var values = [];

  // Select all checkboxes by class name, and use the jQuery :checked special selector
  $('.filled-in:checked').each(function() {

     // Adds the value to the values array
     values.push($(this).val());

  });

  // Log all values
  console.log(values);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sources"></div>
<a id="get">Get selected</a>
```

Comment: it worked. I have one more question.i  have an item in list as "newyork,items". when i get the selected value, value after "," gets truncated.

Comment: It shouldn't be an issue. I've updated the example. Check it.